# Installed it wrong and cannot uninstall ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows, uninstall, partitioning

I installed ubuntu alongside windows 8 but dual boot isn't working.
It doesn't appear in control pannel to simply uninstall.

I have 2 HDD and there are 20GB on the second one (first one is for windows os)
that dont add up so I'm guessing that is where it's installed.

I installed it from usb so I got to ask does it matter what HDD boots after
the usb stick? Because the primary HDD (with windows) was set after ubuntu media.
And the second HDD had 3rd place.
So I dont believe the virtual partition was created on the secondary one.

Anyway how do I get rid of it in order to reinstall it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot) and [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

Use bcd editor to resume Windows bootloader(in place of grub, restart your pc if you can boot into your Windows directly, by directly I mean without seeing grub now). Once you're done with that now format the partition in which u installed ubuntu.